# How to create dev/test environment to test outlook javascript add in on macOS(catalina/bigsur) using azure?

Tags: macos, azure, outlook-addin, azure-devtest-labs

Need to test outlook add in on mac os.Is there a way to setup dev/test environment in microsoft azure using macOS?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/lightweight-base-configuration-microsoft-365-enterprise?view=o365-worldwide
We have input to setup for windows enterprise edition but I need to have for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Although one can manage their DTL resources using any OS, Azure DevTest Labs supports provisioning only Windows and Linux environments as of today. You can share your ideas or submit your feedback about the product [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-lab-services).